# What's wrong with this simple javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, colors

I need to compile the code from this link  http://jsfiddle.net/bQfb6/2/

Looks like something wrong with JavaScript. Text color does not change.

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
.cell1 {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:#eee;
    padding:10px;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.cell1').each(function (i, n) {
    if ($(n).text() < 5) $(n).css('color', 'green');
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell1">20</td>
        <td class="cell1">5</td>
        <td class="cell1">1</td>
        <td class="cell1">3</td>
        <td class="cell1">10</td>
        <td class="cell1">15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

p.s. Sorry for such a noob question, I really need your help to move on

Comment: You are trying to read elements before the exist on the page. It is like eating a pizza before it is made.

Comment: ... and yet no error is shown, as jQuery will happily run .each over an empty object (created by `$('.cell1')` as it finds nothing relevant in DOM). )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to run the code when DOM is already constructed; as it stands now, it's invoked before that, so no elements are found by `.cell1` selector.

Second, the code itself can be simplified (no need to use `.each`, it's enough to set up a callback for `css`) as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('.cell1').css('color', function(_, val) {
    return this.textContent < 5 ? 'green' : val;
  });
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3sqkjj/)</kbd>

Comment: I'm surprised with your answer. +1. textContent returns number?

Comment: No, a String; by the rules of `<` type coercion, however, it'll be cast to Number when compared with a Number. Strictly speaking, one should have wrapped it with `parseInt`, but in this case it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your code inside ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// your code here

});
```

And also, the way you're doing is wrong, do like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cell1').each(function (i, n) {
    if (+($(n).text())< 5){ // + is used to convert into number
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
   }
});
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/429/)

Comment: n is the current object. Not its value.

Comment: Sorry to say that, again your logic is wrong. i is the index. Op needs the text of each element, not index

Comment: Why so complicated? First, `<` comparison operator will cast its left operand to Number if its right operand is a Number; no need to do it explicitly here. Second, what's wrong with `.cell1` selector, why should one use `[class^=cell]` instead?

Comment: ... and I didn't even mention that `i` is an index (which is always a Number btw), it makes little sense comparing index with 5 (that's what `.gt` is for).

Comment: I was leaving my office, so in a hurry I made mistake. And @raina77ow I mistakenly saw cell1, cell2 because of hurry to leave my office, now corrected...

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait till all DOM structure ready and then apply your jquery script. You can wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$(function(){});`

```
$(function(){
  $('.cell1').each(function(i, n) {
     if($(n).text() < 5) $(n).css('color', 'green');
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/bQfb6/198/)**

Answer (score 0):

one more change, you have to use parseFloat for numeric comperison

```
if(parseFloat($(n).text()) < 5)
```